# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<void>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Photography>' on Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I need to get all the data from the firestore database.
I follow this way, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55865045/9139407

```
 Future<Photography> getPhotography() {
  Future<Photography> data =  await db
    .collection('photography')
    .document('0yUc5QBGHNNq6WK9CyyF')
    .setData(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(Photography(
  [AllImages(["list"])],
  "image_url",
  "Shanika",
  "image_url",
  "lovely couple",
  "Bhanuka"
))));

return data;
}
```

The error message is:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Future< void >' is not a subtype of type
>   'Future< Photography> '

**Photography model class**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'Model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Photography{
   List<AllImages> all_images;
   String couplePhoto;
   String female;
   String image_url;
   String info;
   String male;

  Photography();

  factory Photography.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PhotographyFromJson(json);
   Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$PhotographyToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class AllImages {
  final List<String> imageUrl;

  AllImages(this.imageUrl);

  factory AllImages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AllImagesFromJson(json);
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$AllImagesToJson(this);
}
```

**And next problem is, how to add to these data on bloc sink?**

```
  Sink<Photography> get inFirestore => _firestoreController.sink;
```

something like this? but **error is, The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Photography'**

```
final result = db.getPhotography();
inFirestore.add(result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document.setData()` returns a `Future<void>` - meaning that when it completes in the future it won't return any data. That's reasonable for a setter of course. That's why you can't turn it into anything. It's not clear where you intend to get `data` from. You start with an empty(?) `Photography`, encode it, decode it, and store it then expect to return something. What? The original empty object? (You could just return that - but I don't think that's what you want.)

Comment: added my model class. can to tell me how to set firestore data to my model class?

Comment: how to retrieving data?

Comment: The method described in the linked question seems like overkill. Converting the firestore snapshot to and from JSON is rather curious. I'd prefer to just have your class know how to read itself from the snapshot. It's mostly strings, so easy. The list of images is presumably modelled as an array in firestore, but you don't show what's in an `AllImages` class. (Poor choice of name if really what's in there is for example a URL.)